# Instrumentational Amplifier with Summing Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, noise, instrumentation-amplifier, summing

As you all know, most Inst. Amp. examples on the Internet have a 'Differential Amplifier' part as shown below.

But, what would happen if a summing amplifier was used instead ?
What kind of disadvantages I would have ?

Noise elimination and gain are very similar like Diff. Amp. does if my calculations are correct.

Any comment will be appreciated.
Thank you for your consideration.

[image]

Comment: Um.. you would end up cancelling out your differential signal and amplifying the common mode noise instead...

Comment: I think you need to look up the core reasoning in using a differential amplifier (differential mode amplification, common-mode rejection)

Comment: "*...  if my calculations are correct.*" Let's see the calculations! See my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/332390/parallel-opamp-configuration which may help.

Answer (score 1):

With a differential amplifier you are removing the noise and amplifying the signal.  With a summing amplifier you are removing the signal and amplifying the noise.  This *might* be useful in some exotic application, but certainly not common.