# Why use difference amplifiers over instrumentation amplifiers?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, instrumentation-amplifier, cost

I know that instrumentation amplifiers are difference amplifiers with buffered inputs, and I understand why one would select an instrumentation amplifier over a difference amplifier circuit. But is the only reason one would use a difference amplifier over an instrumentation amplifier **cost**, or are there some other good reasons/use cases much better suited to difference amps?

Comment: What does the buffer do?

Comment: @SolarMike see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395195/why-are-two-stages-used-for-an-instrumentation-amplifier/395218#395218

Comment: @PeterGreen perhaps that was the sort of thing I was hoping the OP would find...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *But is the only reason one would use a difference amplifier over an
>   instrumentation amplifier cost?*

No, one great advantage that a difference amplifier provides is substantial "beyond the rails" operation. Consider the ADI difference amplifier below: -

[image]

Look at +IN - it sets the scene for the voltages at the actual inputs to the internal op-amp. If "REF" is tied to internal ground then +IN can approach nearly double the voltage that is applied to +VS.

This cannot be achieved with an InAmp.

But, other difference amplifiers can provide even bigger limits on the terminals such as this one: -

[image]

This can operate with an external input that is about ten times greater than the supplies to the chip.